# How to color vue2 leaflet markers dynamically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vue2leaflet

I have an `google-maps_pin.svg` file which represents a google-maps pin.

I would like to color the different markers (generated with v-for) based on categories (restaurant, art gallery, etc.) dynamically.

Is there a way to achieve that with vue2 leaflet?

Here's my map:

```html
<l-map 
  style="z-index: 0" 
  ref="mapRef" 
  :zoom="zoom" 
  :center="center" 
  @update:zoom="zoomUpdated" 
  @update:center="centerUpdated"
  @update:bounds="boundsUpdated">
  <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
  <l-marker 
      v-for="(markedLocation, index) in marker" 
      :key="'marker-' + index" 
      :lat-lng="markedLocation.location" 
      :icon-url="require('@/assets/googlemaps_markers/google-maps_pin.svg')">
  </l-marker>
</l-map>
```

The color I want to give to the individual pins is stored in `markedLocation.info.category.color` variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can implement by using this property [L.divIcon()](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#divicon).

> Represents a lightweight icon for markers that uses a simple `<div>` element instead of an image. Inherits from Icon but ignores the iconUrl and shadow options.

Your template will be like bellow

```
<div id="app">
    <l-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
      <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></l-tile-layer>
      <l-marker 
        v-for="(item, index) in markers"
        :key="'marker-' + index"
        :lat-lng="item.location"
        :icon="getIcon(item)"></l-marker>
    </l-map>
</div>
```

and your `getIcon()` method will be like this

```js
getIcon(item) {
  return L.divIcon({
    className: "my-custom-pin",
    html: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 34.892337" height="60" width="40">
  <g transform="translate(-814.59595,-274.38623)">
    <g transform="matrix(1.1855854,0,0,1.1855854,-151.17715,-57.3976)">
      <path d="m 817.11249,282.97118 c -1.25816,1.34277 -2.04623,3.29881 -2.01563,5.13867 0.0639,3.84476 1.79693,5.3002 4.56836,10.59179 0.99832,2.32851 2.04027,4.79237 3.03125,8.87305 0.13772,0.60193 0.27203,1.16104 0.33416,1.20948 0.0621,0.0485 0.19644,-0.51262 0.33416,-1.11455 0.99098,-4.08068 2.03293,-6.54258 3.03125,-8.87109 2.77143,-5.29159 4.50444,-6.74704 4.56836,-10.5918 0.0306,-1.83986 -0.75942,-3.79785 -2.01758,-5.14062 -1.43724,-1.53389 -3.60504,-2.66908 -5.91619,-2.71655 -2.31115,-0.0475 -4.4809,1.08773 -5.91814,2.62162 z" style="fill:${item.color};stroke:${item.strokeColor};"/>
      <circle r="3.0355" cy="288.25278" cx="823.03064" id="path3049" style="display:inline;fill:${item.circleColor};"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>`
  });
}
```

You could check here with working **[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4jy27nz)** and please see below screenshot taken from JS fiddle.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for. It works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am using this [pointhi/leaflet-color-markers](https://github.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers)

I have an icon color file with all my icons:

```
export const redIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl:
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color- 
     markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-red.png",
  shadowUrl:
         "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker- 
          shadow.png",
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowSize: [41, 41]
});
```

and then, I use my redIcon in the map like this:

```
<l-marker
  v-for="(item, index) in list"
  :key="index"
  :icon="getIcon()"
>
getIcon() {
  return redIcon;
}
```